# How can I show a Blogger dialog on page load with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the code below, and I want to create a pop up email subscription,
but the problem with this script is that I have to use `<a href='#signup'>Signup</a>` to get a button to click on so as to open this box. However, I want to display this pop up box automatically when I open my blog. I'm using Blogger.

**Please help me to do open this box automatically for a visitor of my website without clicking any button.**

HTML

```
<div class='modalDialog' id='signup'>
  <div><a class='close' href='#close' title='Close'><i class='fa fa-times' /></a>
    <div class='signup-container'>
      <div class='newsletter-sm'>
        <i class='fa fa-envelope-o enve' />
        <h3>Subscribe to Newsletter</h3>
        <p style='text-align:center'>Sign up with your email address to receive news and updates straight in your inbox.</p>
        <form action='https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify' method='post' onsubmit='window.open(&apos;https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=MyBloggerAide&apos;, &apos;popupwindow&apos;, &apos;scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520&apos;);return true' target='popupwindow'>
          <div class='newsletter-sm-bot'>
            <input class='newsletter-input-sm' name='email' placeholder='Enter Your Email' type='text' />
            <button class='newsletter-button-sm' type='submit'>Subscribe</button></div>
          <input name='uri' type='hidden' value='MyBloggerAide' />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto
}

.modalDialog:target>div {
  margin: 8% auto
}

.modalDialog>div {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5% auto;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 200px
}

.close {
  color: #888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px
}

.close:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS has rules for `.modalDialog` which sets opacity to zero and disables click events. You'll need to override that.

If you can add a class name to the modal markup, do so:

```
<div class='modalDialog showOnLoad' id='signup'>
```

And then create a style rule for that class:

```
.modalDialog.showOnLoad {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

If you can't modify the markup you may need to do a global override of the existing `modalDialog` class, possibly limited by a page ID ancestor selector.

Comment: please I need more information beacause I can't close the blogger dialog box

Comment: The trouble is that I can't see what's happening when you click the close button. You'll need to use your browser's inspector to do so, then you can make changes to this or report back. Also, the modal may have options to show it on load so none of this is necessary. Please add to your question about what modal you're using.

Comment: I'm using blogger editor and I'm just beginner in html so please can u apply the modifications that you had sent to me and send me the correct script please

Comment: I explained why that's difficult. You're going to need to learn the basics of debugging HTML and CSS if you want to do work like this.